# Domain won't direct correctly without typing "https://" with it

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, dns, httpd.conf

I recently got https for my domain, purchasing an SSL certificate from namecheap. However if someone types `domain.com` it will direct them to a page stating *Gateway Timeout: can't connect to remote host.* However, if someone was to type `https://domain.com`, it would direct correctly. Typing in `http://domain.com` also will not direct correctly.

The website is running on Amazon Linux AMI. I've tried messing with .htaccess but no luck. Within my httpd.conf file I have the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>    
   ServerName domain.com    
   DocumentRoot rootPath    
   SSLENGINE on    
   SSLCertificatekeyFile keyPath    
   SSLCertificateFile certPath    
   SSLCertificateChainFile chainPath    
</VirtualHost>    
<VirtualHost *:80>    
   RewriteEngine On    
   RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]    
</VirtualHost>    
<VirtualHost *:443>    
   DocumentRoot rootPath    
   SSLENGINE on    
   SSLCertificatekeyFile keyPath    
   SSLCertificateFile certPath    
   SSLCertificateChainFile chainPath    
   RewriteEngine On    
   RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]    
</VirtualHost>
```

I want all traffic to be redirect to https://domain.com automatically.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you have 2  settings for 443?

Comment: Found the proposed solution on another board :http://serverfault.com/questions/664768/redirect-permanent-http-to-https but doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this in order to redirect to SSL version

```
#force SSL
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't rewrite the request to an SSL enabled site from a non-SSL enabled request. You can redirect to one. Negotiating SSL is part of the connection for an https request.

[Example](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html) from Apache's website